# Return Observable after subscription

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

```
const orgsArr = [];
organizations.map(orgid => {
        this.afs.collection('users').doc<Organization>(orgid).valueChanges()
            .map(x => {
               orgsArr.push(x);
            }).subscribe();
});
return Observable.of(orgsArr);
```

orgsArr resturns before subscribe()

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing asynchronous code with synchronous code. Your method calls `orgsArr.push` from within an observable `.map` call, which won't have executed by the time you return `Observable.of(orgsArr)`

You're also mis-using map on `organizations.map`, as map is meant to return something and constructs an array.

You can re-factor this to use a `concat` with all the Observable returned from the orgs mapped `valueChanges()` and then a `reduce` to convert a stream of values into a single array:

```
const orgValueObsArray = organizations.map(orgid => {
        return this.afs.collection('users').doc<Organization>(orgid).valueChanges();
});

return Observable.concat(...orgValueObsArray)
    .reduce((acc, val) => { 
        acc.push(val); 
        return acc; 
    }, []);
```

Comment: Property 'concatAll' does not exist on type type of Observable'

Comment: concatAll doesn't take parameter in rxjs/Observable

Comment: what version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: version rxjs@5.5.6

Comment: Apologies, use `Observable.concat(... orgValueObsArray)` instead